# How to get fields from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to get "`Model`" field and put on `Textbox6`. But how come it does not work.
The problem is that the `Model` field answer will not be shown in the `textbox6`

```
string Query = "Select * from S where Name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Clientno = '" + TextBox2.Text + "';";
command.CommandText = Query;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string Model = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Model"));
    TextBox6.Text = Model;
}
```

Comment: Remove ; from select query

Comment: And pass connection in command line.

Comment: _does not work_ is never give enough information about your problem. Clarify your question first. And most important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Can you post more code from where you initialize command?

Comment: The error is  it cannot show the Model field in the textbox6

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

- Do not use `select *`, instead use `select` *your columns names*
- Do not pass the .Text directly to your query, instead use `parameterized` sql expression
- If Clientno is primary key column or , combination of `Name` and `ClientNo` gives unique result, use `ExecuteScalar`, you don't have to use `ExecuteReader` and loop through the `datareader`

Since you using only one field and want to fill in the textbox, modify your `select` statement to :

```
select top 1 Model from S where....
```

And if you are reading only one row you will not need a while loop. Further, you should always close the reader and put your SqlConnection inside using block.  ( edited as suggested by the comments)

```
If (reader.Read())
{
    TextBox6.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Model"));
 reader.Close();
 }
```

Comment: but i have more field needed to show in textbox1-6

Comment: Do you mean you have 6 textboxes? Then you have to `select Col1..Col6`  and assign it to each textboxes.

Comment: Rather use `if (reader.Read())...` than while/break. Also remember to close the reader after use.

Comment: @sami yes you are right! I will edit my answer.